# Show that the series is not absolutely convergent but is uniformly convergent in the whole complex plane

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, uniform-convergence, absolute-convergence

Show that the series is not absolutely convergent but is uniformly convergent in the whole complex plane.

$$\frac{1}{1+|z|}-\frac{1}{2+|z|}+\frac{1}{3+|z|}-\frac{1}{4+|z|}+...+\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n+|z|}+...$$

My initial thought was to use the Weierstrass M-test but that does not lead me in the right direction or I do not believe it did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update.** Since $$|a_n| = \frac {1} {n + |z|} \sim \frac {1} {n},$$ we have $$\sum |a_n| \sim \sum \frac {1} {n},$$ so the series is not absolutely convergent. Also, we have $$|a_n| = \frac {1} {n + |z|} > \frac {1} {n + 1 + |z|} = |a_{n + 1}|.$$ Hence, the series converges by the Leibniz test. But the convergence of the series does not depend on $z$, so the series converges uniformly.

Answer (score 0):

Not absolutely convergent because
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over n+|z|}>\sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over n+\lceil|z|\rceil}=\sum_{n=\lceil|z|\rceil+1}^\infty{1\over n}=\infty
$$
Uniformly convergent by [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).